# D3 matrix of circles iterating over colors

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to recreate this image in D3:

[image: Matrix of circles]

Its a matrix of 17x17 circles, in which element [0,0] has black color (d3.rgb(0,0,0) ), [17,0] green (d3.rgb(0,1000,0) ) , [0,17] red (d3.rgb(1000,0,0) )and [17,17] yellow (d3.rgb(1000,1000,0) ); the rest of the circles a gradient between these.
I'm a beginner in d3 and java in general, my idea was to do 2 for loops, iterating starting from (x,y) = (0,0) and color (0,0,0) and iterating until getting (1000,1000) as rgb color.

```
grilla_circulos_b = {


  
  var coleccion = []; // Array para devolver
  var cantidad_circulos = 18; //
  var margen = 1 ;
  var col_x = 0;
  var col_y = 0;
  var radio_ini =5 ;

  var x_ini = 0;
  var y_ini = 0;
  var iter = 1;

  for(var x=1; x< cantidad_circulos + margen ; x = x+ margen, col_x = col_x + 1){
    for(var y=1; y< cantidad_circulos + margen; y = y+margen, col_y = col_y + 1){

      if ( x== x_ini & y == y_ini){
        var circle_elem = {
          eje_x : (x*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
          eje_y: (y*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
          radio: radio_ini,
          color: d3.rgb(0,0,0)
        }
      } else {
        var circle_elem = {
          eje_x : (x*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
          eje_y: (y*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
          radio: radio_ini,
          color: d3.rgb(col_x,col_y,0)
        }
      };
      coleccion.push(circle_elem);  
    }
  col_x = 0 + iter


  }
  return coleccion;
}
```

for creating the data and then for plotting:

```
{
  // 1. Creación de un área de dibujo (512x90 pixeles)
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
                .attr("width",400)
                .attr("height",400);
  
    // 2. Asociamos la colección de círculos a componentes gráficos "circle"
  var circulos = svg.selectAll("circle")         // Esta selección da vacio
                    .data(grilla_circulos_b) // Estos son los datos
                    .enter()                     // Para cada entrada
                    .append("circle");           // Agregá un círculo

  // 3. Le decimos a d3 cómo utilizar la información disponible en el arreglo
  // para setear las propiedades cx, cy, r y fill del componente HTML circle
  circulos.attr("cx", function(d) {return d.eje_x;} )
          .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.eje_y;} )
          .attr("r" , function(d) {return d.radio;} )
          .style("fill", function(d) {return d.color;} )
  

  // 4. Retornamos el canvas
  return svg.node(); 
}
```

The problem is that i'm getting:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHSz.png

and since i'm a begginer i cant fully understand where i'm making a mistake. May someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is almost there: I've modified it slightly to compute the colours directly within the loop, rather than incrementing the colours on each iteration:

```
    grilla_circulos_b = {
    
    
      
      var coleccion = []; // Array para devolver
      var cantidad_circulos = 18; //
      var margen = 1 ;
      var col_x = 0;
      var col_y = 0;
      var radio_ini =5 ;
    
      var x_ini = -1;
      var y_ini = -1;
      var iter = 1;
    
      for(var x=1; x< cantidad_circulos + margen ; x = x+ margen){
        for(var y=1; y< cantidad_circulos + margen; y = y+margen){
            
          col_y = y * 255 / cantidad_circulos
          col_x = x * 255 / cantidad_circulos
    
          if ( x== x_ini & y == y_ini){
            var circle_elem = {
              eje_x : (x*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
              eje_y: (y*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
              radio: radio_ini,
              color: d3.rgb(0,0,0)
            }
          } else {
            var circle_elem = {
              eje_x : (x*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
              eje_y: (y*cantidad_circulos) + margen,
              radio: radio_ini,
              color: d3.rgb(col_x,col_y,0)
            }
          };
          coleccion.push(circle_elem);  
        }
      }
      return coleccion;
    }
```

This give me the following SVG[image]